# Tamanho de uma String usando Listas

Tags: python

Como eu faço pra imprimir o tamanho de cada uma das strings que o usuário digitar? Toda vez que eu peço pra imprimir sai quantas strings tem dentro da lista e não a quantidade de caracteres de cada string dentro

````
lista = []
while True:
    nome = str(input())
    if nome == 'fim' or nome == 'FIM':
        break

    lista.append(nome)


print(len(lista))```
````

Answer (score 0):

se vc quiser printar a quantidade de letras em cada string dentro de uma lista vc deve percorrer ela desta forma:

```
lista = []
while True:
    nome = str(input())
    if nome == 'fim' or nome == 'FIM':
        break

    lista.append(nome)


for item in lista:
  print(len(item))
```